# Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are subspaces?

Tags: vector-spaces

Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are subspaces? Explain the answer.

$(a)\ \{(x,y,z) \mid x = 1\}$

$(b)\ \{(x,y,z)\mid z=3x−2y\}$

$(c)\ \{(x,y,z) \mid xy = 0\}$

$(d)\ \{(x,y,z)\mid z=x−2y, z=2x−y\}$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. We are not here to do your homework for you. Homework questions are fine, *as long as the poster shows effort and/or their attempts to solve the problem.*

Comment: i have done it but wasn't too sure about them.

Comment: a) i got not a subspace as it doesn't contain a zero vector, but not too sure

Comment: Good! Your thoughts on the problem are appreciated. What are your thoughts on the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

**Subspace Test**

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $W \subset V$ where $W \ne \varnothing$. $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if

1. For $\mathbf x_1$, $\mathbf x_2 \in W$, $\mathbf x_1 + \mathbf x_2 \in W$
2. For $\mathbf x_1 \in W$ and $k \in R$, $k\mathbf x_1 \in W$

i.e. $W$ must be non-empty and closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

---

$$(b) W =\lbrace (x,y,z) | z =3x -2y \rbrace$$

$W$ is clearly non-empty; 
$$0 = 3(0) - 2(0) \implies (0,0,0) \in W$$

Let $\mathbf x_1 = (x_1, y_1, 3x_1 - 2y_1)$ and $\mathbf x_2 = (x_2, y_2, 3x_2 - 2y_2)$

$$\mathbf x_ 1 + \mathbf x_2 = (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2, 3x_1-2y_1 + 3x_2-2y_2)$$

$$= (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2, 3(x_1+x_2) - 2(y_1 +y_2)) \in W$$

For $k \in R$

$$k\mathbf x_1 =  k \left(x_1, y_1, 3x_1 - 2y_1 \right)$$

$$= (kx_1, ky_1 3(kx_1) - 2(ky_1)) \in W$$

By Subspace Test, $W$ is a subspace of $R^3$

Answer (score 0):

For $a)$, you are correct. Because $\vec{0}$ is not in the set, regardless of what value $y$ or $z$ are, it fails the Subspace Test, and is therefore not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.